# Coloring XML data - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, xml

I am trying to color the tags of XML data. I have an AngularJS app in which I am displaying XML data inside
a modal. The data is coming from a scope variable, displayed with `<pre>` tag:

```
<pre> {{xmldata.xml_one}} </pre>
```

It is prettified but to make it easy to read I want to color the tags (I think it is also called snytax 
higlighting). I tried many examples/libraries/directives for that, the closest I found was [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-highlightjs).
I can color static
xml data with it. It says one can also color dynamically changed content with it but I could not get it to work.

If you know how to do it or suggest something else I would be very happy.

Comment: xmldata should be declare as a scope variable of array type.Can display the variable you define in the scope

Comment: Sorry, I did not get what you are saying. I can display the xml data if that is what you are talking about. The problem is that its font color is all black. I want to change the color of tags.

Comment: If that is html format then can use simple css otherwise if it is in xml format use bellow <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AdvancedStyle>
 <ColorSchemeStyle basecolor="blue" strokecolor="black">
   <Buckets>
        <RangedBucket label="&lt;10"  high="10"/>
    </Buckets>
  </ColorSchemeStyle>
</AdvancedStyle>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive to apply styles to HTML elements.

For example, you can use it for your problem to apply a color for your data.

You can write:

```
<pre ng-style="color:<your_color>">{{xmldata.xml_one}} </pre>
```

To apply the specific `font-color` to your xml.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This colors the whole data which I can also do with changing css properties of <pre> tag. What I want is that if the data is something like this:  <title>Harry</title> <author> Rowling</author> I want for example Harry and Rowling black and title and author tags blue.